# Prevent Gallery from Scrolling on Item Selection

Tags: android, scroll, android-gallery

How can I prevent a `Gallery` from scrolling when an item is selected?
`OnItemClickListener` has so far been unsuccessful for me.

```
gal.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
{
         ((ImageGallery) parent).setScrollingEnabled(false);
}
});
```

I have subclassed `Gallery`:

```
public class ImageGallery extends Gallery
{
  private boolean stuck = false;

  public ImageGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  public ImageGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public ImageGallery(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
  {
    return stuck || super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
      return stuck || super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }

  public void setScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) 
  {
    stuck = !enabled;
  }
}
```

Comment: does .setScrollingEnabled(false) work for you outside of the listener? try using the view itself - maybe ((ImageGallery) view.getParent()).setScrollingEnabled(false);

Comment: It does prevent scrolling, but does not enable it again...

Comment: oh i see .. so you'll have to explain exactly how you want it to act.. when do you want the scrolling to be enabled again? how do you deselect an item on your app?

Comment: Thanks for your patience! :-) Well. In general the scroll behaviour of the gallery is fine. No problem with that. However if you click on an item in the gallery, the gallery will scroll the selected image to the center of the gallery. I would like to prevent this. If a user swipes the gallery should scroll fine from left to right. On selection the item should not move though. It's kinda wacky user experience.

Comment: I understand. well .. actually I dont have any experience with the gallery widget but I believe this auto scrolling feature is implemented in the gallery widget so you would need to go read the actual Gallery class from the android source and find the feature that responsible for this behavior then simply override it in your ImageGallery class and remove it..

Answer (score 1):

extend the gallery and override onSingleTapUp method and give your custom implementation to perform click event,using performItemClick() method.